# Unable to move file from temp using move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, file-upload

I am tryin to upload and store a file (pdfs) in a certain directory

I am using `move_uploaded_file` as such:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userdata"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"]);
```

The script runs but when I check the directory via FTP nothing is there.

Permissions for this directory and its parent directories are `777`.

I am using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my HTML form.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

`var_dump($_FILES);`

gives:

```
array(2) { ["userdata"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(22) "myfile.pdf" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpiUJVu7" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(1398957) } ["userdata2"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }
```

My full code is:

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "wps", "odt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["userdata"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["userdata"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["userdata"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["userdata"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["userdata"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-works")
|| ($_FILES["userdata"]["type"] == "iapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"))
&& ($_FILES["userdata"]["size"] < 4000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

  if ($_FILES["userdata"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["userdata"]["error"] . "<br>";

  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["userdata"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["userdata"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["userdata"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["userdata"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } 

        else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userdata"]["tmp_name"],
          "uploads/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"];
        }
  }
} 

else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

All this if statements pass and I do not recieve any errors.

Comment: put a var_dump of `$_FILES`

Comment: I'd ensure I am using the roght directory. relative directories may give you surprises. I'd use `dirname(__FILE__)`, then build my absolute path, then print it and check it's the right one.

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena thanks - Ive tried adding the absolute path as well, eg: mysite.com.au/uploads/data/

Comment: @shatheesh I've added the output of the dump above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your var_dump says your file names in `input` html  are `coverletter` and `resume`, but you are trying to access as `$_FILES["userdata"]`. Try changing that , it may help

Update :

`uploads` is a typo in `move_uploaded_file()`

Also try checking  `move_uploaded_file` like this

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userdata"]["tmp_name"],"upload/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"]);) {

 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/data/" . $_FILES["userdata"]["name"];

} else {

echo "Move upload seems to be struct !" ;

}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but its my fault for copying that across - I have changed the names here to make it slightly easier. I have fixed it

Comment: upload working ? if not which part of echo is being printed ?

Comment: It echos everything correctly. Eg: Stored in: upload/data/myfile.pdf

Comment: you have mentioned `uploads/data/` in `move_uploaded_file()` . Is that `s` in `uploads` is a typo ?

Comment: Ah yes that did it! Actually `uploads` is correct but I had `upload` in the if statement that checks for duplicates prior to that. For some reason that was messing it up. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: sometimes we need an extra eye, answers updated and glad that we solved it